Can I cut a riser inside FL Studio?
I want to add one of the FL Studio default risers to a song. But this riser has a part where the volume increases, and near the end, it drops. I don't want the drop part.
I suppose I could look in internet where FL Studio stores the audio file, cut it with an audio edition software, and add another version so I can use it the way I want it. But suppose I don't want to alter the FL Studio default folder for order and organization purposes, and I want to alter the riser audio file inside FL Studio, if possible. Is this possible?
Can I cut a riser inside FL Studio?

I'm not familiar with FL Studio, and I'm not sure if I understand your question exactly, but can't you simply play the riser on in empty project and then bounce it or render it, so that you obtain audio recording which you can then cut or process any way you like?

Have you legally purchased FL Studio?  If so, you should check out the Image Line forums, where these questions have probably already been asked and answered, and there are Image Line staff members willing to help.  You seem to be asking a lot of question about how to use this software.

Answer in gif form:

Any audio clip can be trimmed by simply resizing the audio clip.  Use the paint or draw tool, and make sure "stretch audio when resizing" is not selected.
For further questions, see the relevant part of the manual.
For more complex editing, use the built-in audio editor Edison.

This looks so simple, I wonder if OP is missing something else and they cannot get to this point?...

My guess is that they missed step 1: drag audio onto the playlist, and instead loaded it into the sampler.

You can click and drag the end of the riser to cut part of it out as someone as already shown, but if for some reason you are having trouble with that you can also just drop the volume to -inf db right at the part you want off. I'm not sure how it works on FL but a simple google search of "FL studio (your version) automation" should show you how.
Edit: Again im not sure how it works in FL but in Logic Pro there are different (mice?) not sure how to put it in words but it most likely says "smart" "draw" "erase" If you were not able to drag the end you most likely have it on the wrong mouse setting "smart" SHOULD work.
Edit: In the DAW's I personally use you can also right click and save a midi as a wav and it would make an extra. Again I know nothing about FL and it seems like 10x more work to do this and you might not even be able to since it is already an audio file.
